# formatting json data in horizontal order

Tags: python, json, pandas

i have a json file. i am trying to format the data of the json file into horizontal order.

json file

```
"DataBody":
    {
        "data": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "unit": "",
            "format": "integer",
            "key": "Test"
           }
        ],
        "datab": [
        [
         7, 
         1730569828, 
         3490, 
         1608636960,
         30.62,
         1003.82,
         44.14,
         683806.38, 
         2,
         1,
         0,
         0],
        [
         0, 
         1730563432,
         3545,
         1608636960, 
         29.89, 
         1003.52, 
         39.25, 
         557582.38, 
         2,
         1,
         0,
         0
         ],
        [
         1,
         1730579048, 
         3571, 
         1608636960,
         29.79,
         1003.45,  
         41.07, 
         494566.53,  
         2,
         1,
         0,
         0
          ],
        [
         2, 
         1730568292,
         3595,
         1608636960, 
         29.62, 
         1003.40,
         42.72,
         546424.75, 
         2,
         1,
         0,
         0
         ]
```

expected output

```
"DataBody":
    {
        "data": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "unit": "",
            "format": "integer",
            "key": "Test"
           }
        ],
        "dataB": [
        [7, 1730569828, 3490, 1608636960, 30.62, 1003.82, 44.14, 683806.38, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1730563432, 3545, 1608636960, 29.89, 1003.52, 39.25, 557582.38, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1730579048, 3571, 1608636960, 29.79, 1003.45, 41.07, 494566.53, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        [2, 1730568292, 3595, 1608636960, 29.62, 1003.40, 42.72, 546424.75, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

I tired searching everywhere for the solution but cannot find a way to make the data in horizontal order.
Can someone help me.I just want the datab to be in the horizontal order and other thing remain the same

Answer (score 0):

If it's purely for looks, you could turn the lists you want to lie horizontally into strings, i.e.:

```
for i in dict['DataBody'][['datab']:
    dict['DataBody'][['datab'][i] = str(dict['DataBody'][['datab'][i])
```

This isn't particularly helpful if you want to parse the data later, but it would help improve the appearance.

Answer (score -1):

These two images are the same.

JSON files are simply nested dictionaries and JSON parsers don't look at file format, it will just parse everything attached to dataB. Upon saving dataB to a new array after parsing, the two arrays will be the same.